# available overloads in xcode when using tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, indexpath

```
func scroller() {
    let delay = 0.1 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
        if self.chatMessages.count > 0 {
            let lastRowIndexPath = IndexPath(forRow: self.chatMessages.count - 1, inSection: 0)
            self.tblChat.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(lastRowIndexPath, atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Bottom, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting an error where it says Argument labels '(forRow:, forSection:) do not match any available overloads, any help?

Comment: Try `IndexPath(row: self.chatMessages.count - 1, section: 0)`

Comment: @rmaddy You are right, OP uses old style for both calls. Reverted.

Answer (score 3):

In Swift 3 you need:

```
let lastRowIndexPath = IndexPath(row: self.chatMessages.count - 1, section: 0)
self.tblChat.scrollToRow(at: lastRowIndexPath at: .bottom animated: true)
```

You seem to be trying to use the older Swift 2 APIs.

Look at the documentation for `IndexPath` and `UITableView`. And try to use Xcode's autocompletion when typing code. Of course if you copy and pasted older code then that doesn't help.

Comment: that help totally. Thank you so much